# Jenkins with Maven3 and multiple SVN-Modules. How to set differerent parent relativePaths?

Tags: svn, maven, jenkins, parent-pom

I'm struggling with our Jenkins configuration.

I've defined a jenkins-job with multiple SVN-Modules, because i want to checkout from different locations from the **same** svn-repository.

I need to define a *optional module-directory* for each checkout, because if i don't set one, Jenkins will checkout all my modules in the same directory and will always overwrite my .svn-directory (and consequent delete all files, i've checked out before).

So **i set a optional directory for each checkout**. And from this point, it's different to my folder-structure i use, when i checkout all my packages in my eclipse-workspace for exmaple.
Because there is a **flat-hierarchie**.

So i can't use the same *relativePath* in my pom.xml to define the parent, when the *relativePath* is different between jenkins and development.

```
Example:

Jenkins (Tree-hierarchie): <relativePath>../<optionalModuleDir>/pom.xml</relativePath>

Eclipse-Workspace(Flat hierarchie): <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

I tried to use profiles, but i only can set *modules* in profiles, not the parent *relativePath*.

How can i use the same pom.xml with two different parent *relativePath*? Or what should i do instead to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a workaround modify your maven build as follows:

- add a pre build step "Execute shell"/"Execute Windows batch command"
- In this add a script which contains commands to move everything in place or to create symlinks to create the required structure.

when your build starts, after the checkout the sources will be brought into the required structure and then the build itself performs.

Comment: Hey, i tried it with symbolic softlinks, but it doesn't work with the parent relativePath! But the idea is really good. Do you know, if it should work?

Comment: Depending on which maven version you are using it should work. From the looks of it there has been a [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3141) in mvn 2.0.7. I just tried it with a small sample project: 
`\project\pom.xml`  having registered a module
`\module\pom.xml` pointing to project's pom as parent
`\project\module > ..\module` symlink to module in external folder.

`mvn clean install` works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Actually you're right, i tried it with a small sample-project,too and it works fine. 
The strange thing is, that it doesn't work in my real-project.
I'm using Maven 3.0.4.

It seems that there is a bug. I have no idea anymore, what else could be wrong...

Comment: im using mvn 304 too, so it shouldn't be a bug there. you might want to verify the pom file configurations in your project. what error do you get?

Comment: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact "our parent pom" and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 8, column 11 -> [Help 2]


I defined in our parent pom.xml some submodules (../Modules/Module1, and so one..) and maven find them. In all modules i defined "../parent/ as relativePath to the parent. 

"../parent" is a symbolic link to ../../parent

Comment: There is nothing special in the file configuration except i'm using tycho for OSGi support.

Comment: /Parent/pom.xml is the parent, containing all modules. /Modules/Module1, Module2, etc. have relativePath to ../Parent. /Modules/Parent is a symboliclink to /Parent/ Hope that makes it a bit clearer

Comment: I added to my test the relative path setting and created a symlink to the module... It still works for me. I ran into the same issue you're reporting, however that was caused by a typo in the parent pom's artifactId.

Comment: Thanks again. However, there is no typo, because when i change the relativPath direct to the parent "../../Parent/ everything works fine. It must be somehting comical
Guess i'll accept your answer soon..

Comment: Actually i found out, that it is a tycho problem. When i change the packaging-type from "eclipse-plugin" to "jar" it works..